# Spring Cloud Config - Store info in vault (Username/pwd) along with rest of propeties in Git

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

We are right now storing passwords and other configuration related data in git  and filesystem(local) based on profile. This is working fine based on profiles local/dev etc. using SPring cloud config approach.

But to enhance security we have been suggested to use sensitive data in Vault

So i am not clear on how can this be achieved. Whether we will have a single Cloud Config server hosting some properties from Vault and some from Git.

A Config Client  will locate the config server based on CONFIGSERVER_URI so we can not have separate instances running

How to achieve this requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access Git for some properties and Vault for others using the same config server. Access to Vault locations is granted to individual client through the use of a Vault token. The Vault token is passed automatically to the config server as a header at runtime. You would need to configure your config server with the Vault dependencies and add properties to access both Git and Vault something like this (not the 'vault' profile):-

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: git, vault

application:
    name: my-domain-configuration-server

cloud:
    config:
        server:
            git:
                uri: https://mygit/my-domain-configuration
                order: 1
            vault:
                order: 2
                host: vault.mydomain.com
                port: 8200
                scheme: https
```

On your client you need to configure the authorization token supplied by Vault. Note the example below illustrates the property. You can put it into your application yaml files, because it is a per application/per environment token. However I prefer to inject it into the environment during deployment.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://configserver:8888/
      token: <secret token>
```

You should consult the Vault documentation to understand how to authorize your token to access specific locations but the rules may look something like this:-

```
{
    path "secret/myapp-app" {
        policy = "read"
    }

    path "secret/myapp-app/*" {
        policy = "read"
    }

    path "secret/application" {
        policy = "read"
    }

    path "secret/application/*" {
        policy = "read"
    }"
}
```

Finally, it is also possible to access your Git through config server and access Vault directly from your client instead of configuring config server to access both. In this case you need to add the Vault dependencies to the client and configure the client properties to access Vault. You still need the authorization token in the client.